# Convert Flags from C# in Java

Tags: c#, java, enums, byte, enum-flags

I'm translating a part of code from **C#** program to **Java** where is defined a **[Flag] enum** like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum ClientFlags
{
    None        = 0x00000000,
    Flag1       = 0x00000001,
    Flag2       = 0x00000002
    ...
```

And on runtime make mask operations like like

```
ClientFlags.Flag1| ClientFlags.Flag2
```

in my java code i've replicated same class without enum:

```
public static byte None             = (byte)0x0;
public static byte Flag1            = (byte)0x01;
public static byte Flag2            = (byte)0x02;
```

But when i made same operations like

```
byte flags = ClientFlags.Flag1 | ClientFlags.Flag2
```

then result is different!! How I can replicate same operations in java?  Can you help me?

Comment: Define "different"... what are you seeing? Note: anything involving the MSB (i.e. 128-255 in C#, and -128 to -1 in Java) will *appear* different (because in Java `byte` is signed) - but in bitwise terms: it is identical

Comment: Also, your C# code is based on `int`, not `byte` - it would need to be  `public enum ClientFlags : byte` to be `byte`-based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there couldn't be any result at all (including 'different' one) since the code won't compile. Result of bitwise OR operation is `int`, so you have to change `flags` type to `int` or convert result to `byte`:

```
int flags = ClientFlags.Flag1 | ClientFlags.Flag2;
```

or

```
byte flags = (byte)(ClientFlags.Flag1 | ClientFlags.Flag2);
```

Then you'll get the same result as in C# which is `3`.

If you mean that with .NET you can output result as 'Flag1, Flag2' then you probably will have to implement this by yourself.